# Strategies for handling IsSelected and IsExpanded on objects in a TreeView

Tags: wpf, listview, treeview, selection

Imagine a set of contacts and contact groups which are to be displayed in lists and trees. Initially, I just added IsSelected and IsExpanded properties to the common base class and this works well as far as the TreeView goes.

The problem I have is that the objects can appear in different places in the tree (imagine people allocated to more than one group). The result is that when I select an individual person that person is selected everywhere - in every group. This looks a bit unusual but works ok. It gets tricky when the person appears in a separate list and is selected. As the object is the same, the selection appears everywhere in all lists.

How do you manage selection? Is is better to put the objects in temporary selection containers? Is there a good strategy for this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your person class may have multiple IsSelected properties like:

IsSelectedInTree

IsSelectedInList

.

.

.

Then make your bindings more specific:

```
<... IsSelected={Binding IsSelectedInTree}... >
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I was not really happy about adding IsSelected at all to my model object. Adding even more Selected properties for each possible collection that the object might appear in doesn't *feel* like the right way to go...

Comment: You don't need to add IsSelected to all your model objects, just create a base class and inherit from it...

Comment: Sure. My point is that I'm not sure that presentation stuff should be in the model at all. The model doesn't need it - just the view.

Comment: OK, now I see your point. Personally as I follow MVVM, I use IsSelected property in my ViewModels (the middle layer). In your case although it's not a matter of the model, I don't think the view should be responsible for conditional selection logic.